# Cannot delete file in PHP

Tags: php, file, quotes, delete-file, unlink

I've got a website that used to store data in text form (before aquiring db) so now I have a problem deleting a file...

The file has a single quote char in it's name, ("I'mHere.txt"), the site file manager can't delete this file, and it's getting annoying...so I've tried deleting that with php like that:

```
<?php
unlink("I'mHere.txt");
unlink("I\'mHere.txt");
 ?>
```

neither of them works so what do I have to do to delete the file?

EDIT:
file was created like this:

```
$file=fopen($sentence.'.txt',"w");
fwrite($file,$cont);
fclose($file);
```

Edit 2: And I call the delete code from ANOTHER file, the file with quotes is not created anymore, it's just there and cannot be deleted by any means, attempting this results in "file not found" error(path is correct, it works for any file that doesn't have quotes)...

Comment: First, you don't have to escape the *'*. Secondly, are you sure you have the permissions to delete that file? Turn errors and make sure you do.

Comment: It can be a potential of user permission problem. Activate displaying of error messages and check your error_log file.

Comment: path is correct? what does file_exists say?

Comment: To delete a file, you need write access to the parent directory. Does your script have this access? Are you sure the path is correct? Relative paths in server-side scripts are not always pointing where you think they are

Comment: yes it does, after all, the file was created using my php script :P

Comment: @user1126068 Are the script and file in the same directory?

Comment: What does the `E_WARNING` message say?

Answer (score 0):

Did you close the file after writing to it?

```
fclose($filename);

// Then unlink
unlink($filename);
```

Comment: I am not editing the file. it already exists, I just need to delete it.

Comment: You haven't answered the question. You said you have a website which you store data in text, how did you store the data? It sounds like the file is still open on your server since you said you couldn't delete from file manager.

Comment: I couldn't delete it from data manager because it throws an error that it couldn't find the file...

Comment: If you need further help, post the code used to create the file in your question. There is no magic about coding.